# Error of FFmpeg on Java in "av_image_copy_to_buffer" method during decoding H.264 stream

Tags: java, javafx, ffmpeg, decode, h.264

I'm trying to decode H.264 stream, which is sent over Socket from an Android application to a computer. And I also want to show the decoded stream using JavaFX. I searched for a long time, and decided to use JavaCV / FFmpeg. However I got error from FFmpeg. (I was inspired by [this code](https://stackoverrun.com/ja/q/12821597).)

**Questions:**

- Why does FFmpeg make error?
- Is it a correct way to convert `AVFrame` to `javafx.scene.image.Image`?

**I'm using:**

- javacv-platform 1.4.4
- ffmpeg-platform 4.1-1.4.4

**Code:**

This is a part of import and class fields, and method which runs once at the first time. (Actually the content of `initialize()` is wrapped by try~catch.)

```java
    import javafx.scene.image.Image;

    private avcodec.AVCodec avCodec;
    private avcodec.AVCodecContext avCodecContext;
    private avutil.AVDictionary avDictionary;
    private avutil.AVFrame avFrame;

    public void initialize() {
        avCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
        if (avCodec == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't find decoder");
        }
        avCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(avCodec);
        if (avCodecContext == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't allocate decoder context");
        }
        int result = avcodec_open2(avCodecContext, avCodec, (AVDictionary) null);
        if (result < 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't open decoder");
        }
        avFrame = av_frame_alloc();
        if (avFrame == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't allocate frame");
        }
    }
```

And this is a method which is called every time when I receive a packet from Android. `byte[] data` is the packet data starting with `0x00`, `0x00`, `0x00`, `0x01`.

**The place where I get error is `number_of_written_bytes`. It always gets <0.**

```java
    private void decode(byte[] data) {
        AVPacket avPacket = new AVPacket();
        av_init_packet(avPacket);
        avPacket.pts(AV_NOPTS_VALUE);
        avPacket.dts(AV_NOPTS_VALUE);
        BytePointer bytePointer = new BytePointer(data);
        bytePointer.capacity(data.length);
        avPacket.data(bytePointer);
        avPacket.size(data.length);
        avPacket.pos(-1);

        avcodec_send_packet(avCodecContext, avPacket);
        int result = avcodec_receive_frame(avCodecContext, avFrame);
        if (result >= 0) {
            int bufferOutputSize = av_image_get_buffer_size(avFrame.format(), avFrame.width(), avFrame.height(), 16);
            Pointer pointer = av_malloc(bufferOutputSize);
            BytePointer outputPointer = new BytePointer(pointer);
            int number_of_written_bytes = av_image_copy_to_buffer(outputPointer, bufferOutputSize, avFrame.data(), avFrame.linesize(), avFrame.chroma_location(), avFrame.width(), avFrame.height(), 1);
            if (number_of_written_bytes < 0) {
                //The process always come here.
                throw new RuntimeException("Can't copy image to buffer");
            }

            System.out.println("decode success");
            Image image = new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputPointer.asBuffer().array()));
        } else {
            System.out.println("decode failed");
        }
    }
```

Anything is helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: Please try to use this code as reference: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/FFmpegFrameGrabber.java

Comment: @SamuelAudet the example in the question is dealing with a raw h264 stream, the FFmpegFrameGrabber is doing so much it's really hard to understand what is going on if you are new to ffmpeg. Where exactly in this example is AVFrame converted to an Image (or Buffer)? Once you have an AVFrame what's the best way to render it in Java/ JavaFX? There is pretty much no documentation for the FFmpegFrameGrabber (as declared in the wiki) so this is not really an helpful example at all.

Comment: There's an example using JavaFX here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/JavaFxPlayVideoAndAudio.java